# SP2013: Can't add my new content type to a list (0x8102005a)

Tags: content-type, error, exception, internal-server-error

I created a custom content type, and filled it with all of the fields that I need it to have.  However, when I go to add it to my list, I get this fatal error instead.

I checked the ULS logs, nothing but the same message.  I created a new list and tried adding it, same result.

There's only one Google result for 0x8102005a, and it's not helpful.  Is there any way to get a more detailed error message from SharePoint?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.<nativehr>0x8102005a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.<nativehr>0x8102005a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[COMException (0x8102005a): The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.<nativehr>0x8102005a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd) +245

[SPException: The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +146
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.AddField(String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrSchemaXml, Int32 grfAdd) +725
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.AddFieldAsXmlInternal(String schemaXml, Boolean addToDefaultView, SPAddFieldOptions op, Boolean isMigration, Boolean fResetCTCol) +493
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldOnList(SPField field, Boolean bRecurAllowed) +1355
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.ProvisionFieldsOnList() +527
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.DeriveContentType(SPContentTypeCollection cts, SPContentType& ctNew) +704
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentTypeToList(SPContentType contentType) +1788
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.AddContentType(SPContentType contentType, Boolean updateResourceFileProperty, Boolean checkName, Boolean setNextChildByte) +291
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.AddContentTypeToListPage.Update(Object o, EventArgs e) +933
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +146
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3586

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248
```

Comment: I think you are using calculated column, and the formula which you used contain syntax error. To check syntax of formula use excel.

Comment: Check this: http://sympmarc.com/2009/07/29/quick-tip-testing-sharepoint-calculated-column-formulas/

Comment: Close -- it wasn't a calculated column bug, but one of the validations I forgot I had.  Apparently making this change would have broken that formula, so SharePoint (ungracefully) stopped me.  Thanks!